# How to create application using Nokia PC connectivity api using C#

Tags: c#, nokia

i am new to "Nokia PC connectivity api", and i am new to C#. I have to create an application which sends SMS using Nokia mobile X2-01. So is there any link or is there any sample application which helps me and guide me to create application. Thankue

Answer (score 2):

I would forget about any Nokia "connectivity API" and use the far simpler and more understood "AT" commands to send SMS .. example:

```
AT+CMGF=1
OK
AT+CMGS="7789952010"
> Hello World<Ctrl>+<Z>
+CMGS: 44

OK
```

Search Google for "AT+CMGS" for many examples.

Answer (score 0):

YOu would need to have the nokia pc suit installed to sent AT commands like in the project in the following link
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20420/How-To-Send-and-Receive-SMS-using-GSM-Modem

if you use the Nokia PC Connectivity API in your project then there is no need to install the PC Suit. Right now i need to implement this technique too.

The project in the above link worked with my Nokia 7210